# Thread condition never wakes

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that when it runs, it creates a Message object which is put into a linked list in a monitor. At the same time, two other threads wait for this list to get a Message object in it, in a while(linkedlist.isEmpty()) canGetMessage.await(); loop, but even though I'm sending a canGetMessage.signalAll(); command when putting the object into the list, the two other threads never wake.

```
public void deliverMessage(Message m){
lock.lock();

try{
  linkedlist.add(m);
  canGetMessage.signalAll();
 }finally{
  lock.unlock();
 }
}


public Message getMessage(){
lock.lock();

try{
 while(linkedlist.isEmpty()){
  canGetMessage.await();
  }
 return linkedlist.remove(); //returns the item that has been in the list the longest
 }
catch (InterruptedException e) { } //not required to handle these

finally{
 lock.unlock();
}
```

I have println to see when it gets out of the while loop, but this never happens, and I don't know why...

Edit: Just to specify, the lock I'm using is a ReentrantLock

Comment: Why dont you use BlockingQueue with producer-consumer pattern?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: What types are `lock`, `linkedlist` and `canGetMessage`, how are they created? And, yes, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

*Guessing*; you are having problems here:

```
lock.lock();
```

In case sender/receiver use the **same** lock object, this can't work. Receivers **acquire** the lock; and will not release it until the sender has added a new entry to the list.

But the sender can't get to that part; because the sender tries to **lock** on the already locked lock. So the locked lock will block.

The "correct" answer is to use a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to connect sender / receivers - instead of re-inventing something "like a queue". See [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html) for more material how to use BlockingQueue.

Comment: No, canGetMessage.await() releases the lock (assuming the condition has been created from that lock).

Comment: Probably ... lets see what the OP says. If it doesn't help him, i dont mind deleting the answer.

Comment: @Telanore you should NOT use a separate lock. If you want an explanation, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Or move on and use a BlockingQueue (which, I agree, is a better solution anyway).

Answer (score 0):

My apologies to everyone, it turns out the issue lay in the creation of the threads themselves, I had inadvertently been making separate monitors for each thread instead of them all using the same one...

Comment: You either want to improve question and self-answer ... or probably delete your question then.